# How to make a WFF defining some other WFF?

Tags: logic

We have the following symbols: ${\implies},{\land},{\in},{\lnot}.$

Let $a$ be some WFF, e.g. $a{\lor}b$. I want to define it as $b$, which is ${\lnot}({\lnot}a{\land}{\lnot}b)$.

How do I write it? Is there a connective $s$ among the above mentioned symbols or built from them such that $a\, s\, b$ defines $a$ as $b$?

Comment: You can't express a definition purely as a formula. You need English words (or words in whichever language you're writing) in order to convey that what you write is supposed to define something!

Answer (score 1):

We cannot say: "let a formula $a$ be some formula $a∨b$" for two reasons.

*(i)* The purported definition is circular: $a$ occurs both in the *definiens* and in the *definiendum*.

*(ii)* We do not define formulae, but *symbols*. We can do e.g.:

> "let $a → b$ an abbreviation for $¬a∨b$".

In this way we may expand the original language with new symbols: new *connectives*, new individual *constants*, new *predicate* letters.

---

In first-order set theory **without** *equality*, we may add to the original language the new (binary) *predicate* symbol $=(x,y)$ with the definition:

> $(x=y) ↔ ∀z(z∈x ↔ z∈y)$.

This definition allows us to replace every occurence of the formula $∀z(z∈x ↔ z∈y)$ with the abbreviation: $x=y$.